Missing values in data set before DBSCAN
My goal is to identify bots and fraudulent users for an application. Ideally, this would be a regression problem where users are rated on a continuous scale. I have 4 tables that cover different statistics calculated by fingerprinting and fraud score apis. These tables are split by what metric they cover, namely: email data, phone data, ip data, and fingerprint data.
Although I am not exactly sure how these metrics are calculated as they are from external apis, these data sets contain a wide variety of column types. Here are the docs to show the column types: https://www.ipqualityscore.com/documentation/overview
In the end, I would like to synthetically create labels to use with a supervised machine learning algorithm, as the labels I have right now are not the best. I figured that I could either generate labels by first clustering, or, I could generate labels for the supervised ml and using domain knowledge and rules and then use something like isolation forest to compliment the supervised part to keep the algorithm generalized.
However, no matter what approach I take, it is often the case where a user might only have data from 1,2, or 3 of the sources but not all 4. How can I handle missing data here? For example, a user might only sign up with their phone but not an email.
Furthermore, I have around 500k samples and could nearly have 100+ features. Since each set of features comes from a different table, should I use PCA to minimize the number of features?

Welcome to Cross Validated :) Please could you edit your question and add some further details about 1) Your research question 2) some further details about the 4 tables - where do they come from / how was the data collected, 3) any other details that would help us understand your question better :)

@RobertLong I've edited the post. Does that provide better clarification?
